# PJLINK response is ambiguos

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to implement PJLINK protocol for my project. I have written a python script that talks over a socket with my projector on an assigned IP address and port no 4352 (default port number for PJLINK protocol) 
Here is the code snippet:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)    
server_address = (ip address,4352)    
s.connect(server_address)    

s.send("%1POWR ?")   # PJLINK query to check power status    
time.sleep(2)    
res = s.recv(1024)    
print (res)

s.close()
```

Now every time I execute this piece of code I get the following output :

> PJLINK 1 568f1258

the last 8 bits vary in every other execution of code.I am not able to understand how are these bits encoded and what do they mean coz according to the PJLINK manual the output should be something like:

%1POWR=1

kindly help. thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please format your code by editing the question. There is a tool bar icon "{}" for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed this from the [PJLink Specifications](http://pjlink.jbmia.or.jp/english/data/5-1_PJLink_eng_20131210.pdf):

> ## 5. Authentication
>
> ### 5.1. Authentication procedure
>
> To enter into communication with each other using PJLINK commands, both the Projector/Display and the CONTROLLER must carry out the authentication procedure in advance. …
>   An authentication procedure is executed once after each establishment of TCP/IP connection. …
>   The Projector/Display returns a response … The response includes the header
>   ‘PJLINK’, a ‘1’ indicating authentication procedure, and a random number sequence.

This is exactly what you observed. See the specification for more info.